# Is asking about the nature of a religion's god on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Currently Worldbuilding has a [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/85128/2113) asking for more information about whether the Moon Goddess and Horned God of Wiccan mythology are tripartite or not.  The poster also wants to know what the three parts would be for each.

Note:  I'm less worried about whether the question is formed properly for Mythology.SE and more worried about whether it could be written properly.  So if it is Too Broad because it asks about two deities at once or if it is unclear what information would answer the question, those are fixable problems.  But if perfectly written, could that be on-topic?  Feel free to explain how the question should be written to be on-topic.

@HDE226868 commented:

> I don't think this would be good for Mythology, not because it's about a mainstream religion (we do handle questions about stories from Judaism, Christianity, Islam, Hinduism, etc. there), but because it's not about a Wiccan mythological story.

I'm not sure that I understand the distinction here.  It seems to be saying that "What is Odin god of?" is off-topic and "How did Odin lose his eye?" is on-topic.  If you agree with that viewpoint (the question should be off-topic here regardless), please explain why you feel that it would muddy the site's purpose (or whatever you feel the problem is).

Note:  the question is currently closed on Worldbuilding.  I don't know that I agree with that either, but that's the current situation.  The claim is that it is too much about the real world beliefs of Wiccans and not enough about creating a fictional world, but that's a Worldbuilding problem.

Comment: Not sure why that question would be off topic here. I can think of several similar questions. Go ahead and ask it.

Comment: I don't think HDE226868 is calling the question off topic. The issue identified in his comment - not being focused on a story or small set of stories - is more an issue of broadness and clarity than topicality. I cannot think of any reason why a more focused version of the question wouldn't be welcomed here.

Answer (score 3):

Wiccans do not regard the God and the Goddess as deities in the way that many other religions do.  The names God and Goddess are used by some Wiccans purely as anthropomorphic representations of the Male and Female energies present in the universe.

Depending upon which group you talk to, these energies may be known as the White and the Red, the Michael and the Mary, the Widdershins and the Deosil, or by other names.

The development of the respects paid to the God and Goddess over time could well be on-topic for Mythology.  Modern Wicca derives its beliefs from oral traditions passed down for centuries.  They vary from place to place.

Is this not mythology in its purest form?  Word the question to cover the nature of the myth, this should work here.